# Jscript image tag creation gives an error

Tags: image, jscript

```
function pushImage () {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = '/waroot/chart/chart.png';
    document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = "<img src='/waroot/chart/chart.png'>";
    document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = img;
}
```

Test 1 works and shows the image, but test 2 doesn't. I am not sure how to solve it but i will need the way test 2 works further along my project since i'm going to have to circle through a large amount of images.

The images are created by `JFreeCharts`, saved to `png` and then have to be posted to a site. As a side question: is it possible to push the freecharts objects straight to the `jscript` instead of having to save them prior (i could throw them into the dictionary and then look them up later but i'm not sure if this works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.appendChild(img)` instead of `.innerHTML`:

```
function pushImage () {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = '/waroot/chart/chart.png';
    document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = "<img src='/waroot/chart/chart.png'>";
    document.getElementById("test2").appendChild(img);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d9Pvp/)

This is because `img` is an image object, not an html string, so you have to append it to the DOM.

P.S., don't forget that the `alt` attribute is required in the `img` tag!